# Ajax status update in one page with one button

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I am trying to update the status for my orders on the same page where it's displayed with an ajax HTML.

Displaying works just fine, but I want to set the status the the next one with only one click so I figured to use ajax for it too.

**My ajax PUT for the next status**

```
    $(function () {
        $(document).on('click', 'button#order_update', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          let newStatus = '';
          if ($(this).data('status') == 'pending') {
            newStatus = 'confirm';
          } else if ($(this).data('status') == 'confirm') {
            newStatus = 'processing';
          } else if ($(this).data('status') == 'processing') {
            newStatus = 'picked';
          }

          let formStatusData = new FormData();
          formStatusData.append('order_id', $(this).data('order'));

          $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: '{{ route("update-order-status") }}',
            data: formStatusData,
            success: (response) => {
              console.log(response);
              $(this).data('status', newStatus);
              $(this).text(newStatus.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + ' order');
            }
          });
        });
      });
```

**My ajax for the html**

````
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/order/view/all',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success:function(response){
            $('#pimage').attr('url','/'+response.product.product_thambnail);
            var product_name = $('#pname').text();
            var id = $('#product_id').val();
            var quantity = $('#qty').val();
            var OrderView = ""

            $.each(response.orders, function (key,value){
                var productsList = '';
                $.each(value.product, function (key,value) {
                    productsList += `
                        <div class="row gx-4">
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <div class="pos-task-product">
                                    <div class="pos-task-product-img">
                                        <div class="cover" style="background-image: url(${value.product_thambnail});"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pos-task-product-info">
                                        <div class="flex-1">
                                            <div class="d-flex mb-2">
                                                <div class="h5 mb-0 flex-1">${value.product_name_en}</div>
                                                <div class="h5 mb-0">${value.pivot.qty} DB</div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pos-task-product-action">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Complete</a>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-default">Cancel</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    `;
                });

                OrderView += `<div class="pos-task">
    <div class="pos-task-info">
        <div class="h3 mb-1" id=""><td>Üzenet: ${value.notes}</td></div>
                                <div><div><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-theme rounded-0 w-150px data-status="${value.status}" data-order="${value.status}" id="order_update">Confirm Order</button></div></div>
        <br>

        <!-- You can safely remove this if not needed

        <div class="mb-3">${value.product_id}</div>
        <div class="h4 mb-8">${value.product_name}</div>

        -->

        <td>   </td>
        <div class="mb-2">
            <span class="badge bg-success text-black fs-14px">${value.status}</span>
        </div>
        <div><span class="text">${value.created_at}</span> Beérkezett</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pos-task-body">
        <div class="fs-16px mb-3">
            Completed: (1/4)
        </div>
        ${productsList}
        </div>
    </div>`


            });

            $('#OrderView').html(OrderView);

        }
    })

}
OrderView();```



**Im currently trying to use this button inside the HTML ajax**<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-theme rounded-0 w-150px data-status="${value.status}" data-order="${value.status}" id="order_update">Confirm Order</button></div>
````

**I tried using processData: false, but it just kills the process and the button is unusable. Please help.**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have many identifiers `#` with the same name.

id must be unique.
Replace in code

```
$(document).on('click', 'button#order_update'
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.order_update'
```

---

and

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-theme rounded-0 w-150px data-status="${value.status}" data-order="${value.status}" id="order_update">Confirm Order</button>
```

to

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-theme rounded-0 w-150px order_update" data-status="${value.status}" data-order="${value.status}">Confirm Order</button>
```

You still have the problem that you didn't close the class quote after w-150px, I closed it in the formatted code